# How can I create a SharePoint 2007 application page with Visual studio 2008?

Tags: 2007, visual-studio

I have downloaded [Visual Studio 2008 extensions for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=21082) and create an empty SharePoint project (New => SharePoint => empty). However, I cannot find an item which create application page like SharePoint 2013 (right-click project => Add => new item => application page)

So, can any one tell me how to create a SharePoint 2007 app page project in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2007 development, there is no such template to create application pages.You have to create and deploy it manually.

You have to add `aspx` page in the project and inherit it from `"LayoutsPageBase"` and implement it. Then you need to deploy it manually.Paste the .aspx file Layout folder and deploy dll to GAC.

This is high level explanation.Please find following Link for step by step details

https://jamilhaddadin.com/2009/03/04/how-to-develop-custom-asp-net-pages-with-sharepoint-2007-full-tutorial/

http://aarohblah.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-create-customized-application.html